# How to align horizontally inside \valign

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have found somewhere on Stack Overflow that I specify a table column-vise by using `\valign`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,placeins}
\begin{document}
\valign{
&\hrule\vskip 2pt plus 1fil\hbox{\strut\quad #\quad}\vfil\cr
Parameter & Value\cr
$a$ & $10\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    0& 1& 1&\\
    1& 0& 1&\\
    1& 1& 0&\\
    \end{pmatrix}$\cr
$b$ & $20$\cr
$\gamma_{c}$&$\frac{a}{b}$\cr
}
\end{document}
```

This is all good but the problem is that in one column the first row text "a" is much shorter than the matrix below it. How could I make the column to be centered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing `valign` for this case, rather than the `tabular` environment, which would seem to better fit the problem?  Don't ue `minimal` class.  Also, remove the trailing `&` on each matrix row.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can tabular be used for defining table column-vice? The table is horizontal and I'd like to keep parameter and value close.

Comment: Is something like this what you mean?  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,placeins}
\begin{document}
\valign{
&\hrule\vskip 2pt plus 1fil\hbox{\strut\quad #\quad}\vfil\cr
Parameter & Value\cr
\hskip.5in$a$ & $10\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    0& 1& 1\\
    1& 0& 1\\
    1& 1& 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}$\cr
$b$ & $20$\cr
$\gamma_{c}$&$\dfrac{a}{b}$\cr
}
\end{document}`.  I removed trailing `&` in `pmatrix`, added `\hskip` before `$a$`, and changed `\frac` to `\dfrac`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes. However, outside of minimal example there are multiple columns that need adjustment. I hope not to have to shift each one manually.